# 301 Redirect In PHP

Tags: php, redirect

I keep hearing about a 301 redirect. Is it the same as doing this?:

```
<?php
  header("Location: https://www.example.com/");
  exit();
?>
```

What is the difference between doing this or redirecting in a different way. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation (https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.header.php) header('Location: ...') returns with a status code of `302` which means 'moved temporarily'.
If you would like to tell the browser that this is a permanent redirect, use a 301 status code, like this:

```
header("Location: https://www.example.com/", true, 301);
```